# Laravel: How to fix laravel new project error?

Tags: php, laravel, project, new-operator

I'm trying to create a new project using the command: `laravel new project`
But, it is giving error of "Could not open input file: C:\Users*User Name*"
Is it okay to move to the project like this, or if there is something wrong how to fix this?

```
C:\Users\Radeon RX>laravel new Dummy3
Crafting application...
Could not open input file: C:\Users\Radeon
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You have space in directory. Please replace it with - or _

Answer (score 2):

It is because there is space in the directory which is causing an error.

You should replace it with - or _ to make it work.

`Radeon RX` replace it to `Radeon_RX` or `Radeon-RX`.

Make sure, no parent directory should have space in it.

Comment: But, I can't rename the folder.

Comment: @Ovee you can choose another folder to install your project than the window's default user folder.

Comment: @N69S It's not working bro, I've to install on that folder because of the Composer location.

Comment: I see you are using Windows, xampp or wamp or something, so whatever software you are using, they have there www or htdocs folder in it, you should pull there only.

Comment: @Ovee you can do `C:\anotherFolder> C:\Users\Radeon RX\laravel new Dummy3` no need to be in the same folder to run the command.